# django django-imagekit django-cumulus random syntax errors

Tags: django, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, imagekit, django-imagekit

I have been using `django-imagekit` and `django-cumulus` now for a while in my app with Rackspace and I seem to be getting random errors, these do not occur on a regular basis, but more on an irregular basis.

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

The error seems to appear on `{% for gun in guns %}`

`<div style="margin-top: 20px;">

     {% for gun in guns %}`
         `<div style="float:left;padding-right:6px;margin-bottom:20px;">`
            `<a href="/gunsafe/detail/{{ gun.id }}"><img src="{{ gun.thumbnail_image.url}}" width="166px"></a><br />`
            `<a href="/gunsafe/detail/{{ gun.id }}">{{ gun.brand }}</a>`
         `</div>`
    `{% endfor %}

</div>`

Now I got a different error...

> Caught an exception while rendering: (8, '_ssl.c:480: EOF occurred in violation of protocol')

Comment: What Dominic Rodger said. Go ahead and add more details about these errors.

Comment: I have updated with some of the errors that I keep getting.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or anything that could block port 443?